# Keep python scheduler script running on Windows

Tags: python, apscheduler

Let's say I have a python script like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

sched = BackgroundScheduler()

def SchedulerTest():
    file1 = open("C:/Stuff/Stuff2/SchedTest.txt","a") 
    L = [str(datetime.now()) + ' | Testing this scheduler.' + '\n']
    print(L)
    file1.writelines(L)
    file1.close()

sched.add_job(SchedulerTest, 'interval', seconds=15, start_date="2020-04-24 07:30:00", end_date="2021-01-01 10:59:00", id='id_SchedulerTest')

sched.start()
```

saved in a file called SchedTest.py in this directory: C:\Stuff\Stuff2\
along with a blank text file called SchedTest.txt

The process does work as expected in my Jupyter notebook, so long as I have the notebook actively loaded.

How do I run the process and keep it running on my Windows PC without running the script through my Anaconda Navigator-loaded Jupyter notebook?

The below seem unsuccessful as evidenced by an empty SchedTest.txt file, though no error messages popped up for any of them: 
  
1. Make a file named SchedTest_start.cmd with the following contents then double-click it:

```
echo "Starting my Scheduler Task"
call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Stuff\Stuff2\SchedTest.py"
pause
```

2. Opening cmd and typing python C:\Stuff\Stuff2\SchedTest.py

3. Opening cmd and typing pythonw C:\Stuff\Stuff2\SchedTest.py

4. Opening cmd and typing conda run C:\Stuff\Stuff2\SchedTest.py 


UPDATE------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Combining the solution by @Chiheb Nexus plus the comment by @Alex Grönholm worked:
1. Change the script to use a blocking scheduler rather than a background one

```
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

def SchedulerTest():
    file1 = open("C:/Stuff/Stuff2/bl/SchedTest.txt","a") 
    L = [str(datetime.now()) + ' | Testing this scheduler.' + '\n']
    print(L)
    file1.writelines(L)
    file1.close()

sched.add_job(SchedulerTest, 'interval', seconds=15, start_date="2020-04-24 07:30:00", end_date="2021-01-01 10:59:00", id='id_SchedulerTest')

sched.start()
```

2. Make a file named SchedTest_start.cmd with the following contents then double-

```
click it:<br>
echo "Starting my Scheduler Task"
call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Stuff\Stuff2\SchedTest.py"
pause
```

Comment: You really should use BlockingScheduler for this since you're not running anything else in the script.

Comment: This plus @Chiheb Nexus's answer made it work.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your script is in `C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\project` and you've already have a `virtualenv` (`venv`) under the project folder.

In other words your project folder looks like this:

```
. 

├── project

├── venv

├──  your_script.py

└──  ... (other files)
```

What you have to do is to create a `.cmd` file like this example:

**my_scheduler.cmd**

```
echo "Starting my Scheduler Task"
call "C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\project\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\project\your_script.py"
pause
```

Then finally, open [`Windows Task Scheduler`](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) and add the `.cmd` file under the `basic task` submenu.

Also, you may consider that instead of using the `venv's Python executable` you can use your System Python executable. **But it's not recommended to do this**. The rule say: **Each project should have it's own dependencies and should be run under it's proper virtualenv**.

**Bonus:**

`ApScheduler` can act weirdly due to this behaviour:

> If the execution of a job is delayed due to no threads or processes
>   being available in the pool, the executor may skip it due to it being
>   run too late (compared to its originally designated run time). If this
>   is likely to happen in your application, you may want to either
>   increase the number of threads/processes in the executor, or adjust
>   the misfire_grace_time setting to a higher value

For more informations visit [APScheduler documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#missed-job-executions-and-coalescing)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response, but what is a virtual environment and how would I apply the concept to this project?
I do understand what you mean by the my_scheduler.cmd file

Comment: @WesHowell This is some docs about [virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I don't know why, but this didn't seem to work.  I updated my original post with more detail and a simpler example.

Comment: @WesHowell Do you have an errors ? If not the script is launched but due to APScheduler behaviour it can not be executed.

Comment: I had no errors, however, nothing was written into the text file.  This means the every-15-second process didn't run even once.  It does run and write to the text file without issues if I run the same script as a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: @WesHowell I use this setup in Production every day. You have somthing wrong in yours. Check it. I can't anticipated what you've done sorry.

Comment: @Alex Grönholm's suggestion to use BlockingScheduler instead plus your recommendation combined worked!

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Python from [python.org](https://python.org)
2. Press Win + X and select "Command Prompt"
3. Run `pythonw C:\Stuff\Stuff2\EmailScheduler_PPE.py`

Understand the consequences. Only run the script if you trust the libraries you used!

`pythonw` means to run the script with Python without showing the console window. You may want to use `python` first to debug. Step 3 may not do anything visually, but the script should be started in the background.

Comment: I don't know why, but this didn't seem to work.  I updated my original post with more detail and a simpler example.